# Preventing double event binding in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, binding

I have this code

```
$(".generate").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("jsonfile.json").done(function(data) {

        if (parseInt(data)>0) {
            $(".mybutton").click(function() {
               alert(data); 
            });
        }

    });
});
```

When the "generate" button is clicked, the getJSON function is called and if data says "ok" then I can press the "mybutton" to alert the data;

Only problem is if I press the "generate" button a few times (I want this to happen), the "mybutton" will alert "hello" also a number of times (depending on how many times I clicked the generate button).

I have tried `e.stopPropagation()`, but this did not help.

Comment: Please try to explain what you want to do. It is not very clear to me. You reassign `click` on generate everytime and you want to alert the data returned. I don't see anywhere in your code "hello". Your HTML markup is also relevant so please post it here.

Comment: I have edited the text.
I have a button which generates JSON code of which I need to proccess and if I get the right paramters trigger other buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that every time you click the button `.generate` you add a new event handler on the element with the class `.mybutton`

It's not very clear what you're trying to do, but if the purpose is to store the data you get from the ajax call, you can do like this:

```
//data container
var localData;

//will show the actual content of the variable when .mybutton is clicked
$(".mybutton").click(function()
{
    alert(localData);
});

//this will update the variable when .generate is clicked
$(".generate").click(function() 
{
    $.getJSON("jsonfile.json").done(function(data) 
    {
        if (parseInt(data)>0)
        {
            localData = data; 

            //this will trigger the click event on the button .mybutton that will fire the handler with the alert
            $(".mybutton").trigger('click'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation with [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like

```
    $(function() {
     var buttonData = {};
     $(".generate").click(function() {
         $.getJSON("jsonfile.json").done(function(data) {

             if (parseInt(data) > 0) {
                 buttonData = data;
             }

         });
     });
     $(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function() {
         alert(buttonData);
     });
 });
```

and bind it outside of the `getJSON` success handler

Comment: yes I thought of that, but the data is uniqe each time. And got through jsonfile.json.

Comment: @NirTzezana, why not bind it outside the click and success handler? Bind it on ready

Comment: But I won't get the "data" var and be able to use it if its bound outside.

Answer (score 1):

You could unbind and re-bind the handler each time

```
if (parseInt(data)>0) {
    $(".mybutton").off('click').click(function() {
       alert(data); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you try it this way? (Didn't test this, but should work)

```
$(".generate").click(function() {
   $(this).unbind('click').next()
    $.getJSON("jsonfile.json").done(function(data) {

        if (parseInt(data)>0) {
            $(".mybutton").click(function() {
               $(this).unbind('click').next()
               alert(data); 
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you always rebind the event. Is the button removed from the DOM after you click the generate button?

If not you could only bind the event once and just disable the button while no data is available:

```
$(".mybutton").prop('disabled', true); // initially disable
$(".mybutton").click(function() { // bind the event once
    alert(data); 
});

$(".generate").click(function() {
    $(".mybutton").prop('disabled', true); // disable if new data starts to generate
    $.getJSON("jsonfile.json").done(function(data) {

       if (parseInt(data)>0) {
           $(".mybutton").prop('disabled', false); // enable if everything is ok
       }
   });  
});
```